# Filtering result from running start-process in emacs/elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have the following code to run python and get the result in *scratch* buffer.

```
(defun hello ()
  "Test, just prints Hello, world to mini buffer"
  (interactive)
  (start-process "my-process" "*scratch*" "python" "/Users/smcho/Desktop/temp/hello.py")
  (message "Hello, world : I'm glad to see you"))
(define-key global-map "\C-ck" 'hello)
```

The python code is as follows.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "hello, world from Python"
```

Using C-c k gives me the following code in *scratch* buffer.

```
hello, world from Python

Process my-process finished
```

I don't need the last part, as it's not from the python. Is there a way not to get this string or deleting this one effectively?

### Added

Trey helped me to get an answer.

```
(defun hello ()
  "Test, just prints Hello, world to mini buffer"
 (interactive)
  (insert (shell-command-to-string "python /Users/smcho/Desktop/temp/hello.py"))
 (message "Hello, world : I'm glad to see you"))
(define-key global-map "\C-ck" 'hello)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
(shell-command-to-string "/Users/smcho/Desktop/temp/hello.py")
```

That will return a string that you can insert in the *scratch* buffer like so:

```
(with-current-buffer "*scratch*"
  (insert (shell-command-to-string "/Users/smcho/Desktop/temp/hello.py")))
```

Comment: I run the code, and the result seems to go to minibuffer, not to the current buffer or anything.

Comment: @prosseek Not sure what you're wanting here.  The above returns a string.  You can have it put in the current buffer by wrapping it with `(insert (shell-command....))`.  Generally one doesn't program emacs-lisp by dumping strings into the *scratch* buffer and working on them...